# What does "completely expressive hypothesis space" mean in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

I understand the term "hypothesis space".

> A classifier must be represented in some formal language that the computer can handle. Conversely, choosing a representation for a learner is tantamount to choosing the set of classifiers that it can possibly learn. This set is called the hypothesis space of the learner.

References

- [A Few Useful Things to Know About ML](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2347755)

Chapter 3 of [Tom M. Mitchell. Machine Learning (free)](http://profsite.um.ac.ir/~monsefi/machine-learning/pdf/Machine-Learning-Tom-Mitchell.pdf) uses a term "completely expressive hypothesis space"

> Decision tree learning is one of the most widely used and practical methods for
>   inductive inference. It is a method for approximating discrete-valued functions that
>   is robust to noisy data and capable of learning disjunctive expressions. This chapter
>   describes a family of decision tree learning algorithms that includes widely used
>   algorithms such as ID3, ASSISTANT, and C4.5. These decision tree learning methods
>   search a completely expressive hypothesis space and thus avoid the difficulties
>   of restricted hypothesis spaces. Their inductive bias is a preference for small trees
>   over large trees.

what does that mean here?